# SQL Automatically rounding off variable

Tags: sql, dbvisualizer

This is my code running on Vertica server on DB Visualizer.

```
@echo ${Margin||77.5||decimal(5,2)||where noshow}$;
```

When I run this line, I'm getting '77' as my value instead of '77.5'.

```
select ${Margin}$ + 0
```

Could someone please tell me how to NOT round off my variable? I need it to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select ${Margin}$ + 0.00
```

Sometimes, compilers cast a result based on the literal values in the statement, so, since 0 would be considered an INT, the result is probably being cast to an INT.  By making the literal a float, it might make the result a float and not truncate.